# Reading from JSON file into a Dictionary

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to work with the new`MLGazettee`r as part of the Swift `CreateM`L. It supports the `MLTagger` processes by tagging some word.

The WWDC videos  and documentation show code like the following:

```
let entities = ["vehicle": ["car", "bike", "plane"],
            "food": ["tomato", "flour", "sugar", "salt", "potato"]]
let gazetteer = try MLGazetteer(dictionary: entities)
let newModel = "test"
try gazetteer.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: ".../Desktop/" + newModel + ".mlmodel"))
```

This works and the property "entities" is written as a dictionary and used by the `MLGazetteer`.  My problem is I would like to have a larger gazetteer.  I would like to have the data read from a file with the same format as "entities".  How can I read this in in the same format?

I have tried something like:

```
newURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "gazetteer data", withExtension: "json")!
let newData = try Data(contentsOf: newURL)
let newEntities = Dictionary(from: newData)
```

But this failing at the Dictionary(...) with the following: "Cannot invoke initializer for type 'Dictionary<_, _>' with an argument list of type '(from: Data)'"

Is there an easy way to read from a file to a `Dictionary` am trying?

Comment: I tried using json.  I ended up with json I could not get to be a dictionary.  Perhaps that is an approach I should figure out.

Comment: If your file contains json your should decode the data as `let newEntities = try JSONDecoder().decode([[String:[String]]].self, from: data!)` or similar

Comment: Trying to decoder as suggested.  And getting a runtime error:  "debugDescription : "Expected to decode Array<Any> but found a dictionary instead.""

It seems to think it is reading a dictionary, but is not working as one.

Comment: Think about what your datamodel looks like in your code: a key and then an array of names as the value, this is your basic struct; and then you have an array of these structs. The json you import should match this.

Comment: Do some proper research on json and decoding and using `Decodable` protocol, plenty of information available and most certainly your best way forward.

Comment: I can read it in, I cannot read it in with a format the dictionary accepts.

Comment: can you provide sample json?